# Was Luhmann influenced by Schelling?

Tags: schelling, natural-philosophy, luhmann

Just wondering. I know little about Schelling and was reading a commentary by Forster on his philosophy of nature. Some of the ideas, such as "irritability" and production of the *Umwelt* recalled terms from Niklas Luhmann's systems theory.

A quick, incomplete glance at some of my Luhmann indexes doesn't find Schelling listed. Is there any explicit influence or connecting lineage here, or just a coincidence of common terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to prove a negative, but I am pretty confident that there is no *direct* influence after checking a lot of English *and* German sources.

They do have some similarities, probably because Schelling was one of the first to have a systematic philosophy of nature.

Some sources suggest an indirect influence via Friedrich Schleiermacher though, maybe that is a place where you can continue your search.

Not much, but that is all I could find.

Comment: Thanks for looking, sounds pretty convincing. And I think it was by your recommendation that I got Forster's "The 25 Years of Philosophy," such a funny title. Very good, kind of idiosyncratic, and I'm not yet up to Hegel.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander The book is a jewel. Even if one does not agree with his line of argument, he provides all the source material to build one's own.